# Is there a way to edit cells in the DataGrid XAML control for UWP with only one click or when they get focus?

Tags: datagrid, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I know this question has already been asked for WPF DataGrid but the solutions don't apply to DataGrid from Windows Community Toolkit used in UWP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [SelectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.datagrid.selectionchanged?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) and [BeginEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.datagrid.beginedit?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) event to do this like following.

XAML code:

```
<controls:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1"
…
SelectionChanged="dataGrid1_SelectionChanged">
```

Code behind:

```
private void dataGrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            dataGrid1.BeginEdit();         
        }
```